# Passing POJOs vs Strings (json encoded) to my applications WebApi

Tags: java, android, oop, architecture

I have some forms and databases that will fill up some POJO's with data.  Using Json (gson) I"m going to upload the data to my web server.  The server will send back a responses that will eventually be placed back in objects.

My question is, should I encode/decode my objects to json and then pass strings back and forth to my WebApi class?  Or should I pass my WebApi class my object and have it pass back an appropriate response object (based on the method I call.)?

So at when I call my Api that has all the http conection stuff in it, it would look something like this.

```
myWebApi postSomeData( jsonData );  //
```

Should jsonData be a pojo that will be encoded into json string inside myWebApi or should I encode it into json and pass in a string.

Or in otherwords

```
String postSomeData( String jsonData){
web code here..
}
```

or

```
ResponsePojo postSomeData( PostData myData){
...
myMapper.MapFrom(myData); //converts pojo to json
...
webcode
}
```

At some point there will be images included in the data needed to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using json for data transfer, it will make your services technology independent.

You can use flexjon to serialize java objects in a pretty direct way on the server side.

For images you will need to do post http POST anyway, this should be done separately from data submit since an error in a image upload should not result in data loss. Typically you'll associate the id of your data object in the uploaded image (or reversly), so you need to insert your object to db and wait for the response to insert the dependency id to your image.

Best Regards,
Zied Hamdi
http://1vu.fr

Comment: Hello, Thank you for responding.  I hadn't considered what you had mentioned about images.  I'll have to take that into account when I get to those methods.  However I my main question is not quite answered I'll edit my original post with more details.  Thanks again.